# install of ubuntu touch onto a tablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have nearly completed the install but got this message;

```
david@Inspiron-8100:~$ phablet-flash -d grouper -b
Device detected as grouper
Download set to http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview//daily-preinstalled/current
Starting new HTTP connection (1): cdimage.ubuntu.com
Starting new HTTP connection (1): cdimage.ubuntu.com
Download directory set to /home/david/Downloads/phablet-flash/127
Retrieving files
Not enough space in /data, found 854M
david@Inspiron-8100:~$ phablet-flash -d grouper -b
Device detected as grouper
Download set to http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview//daily-preinstalled/current
Starting new HTTP connection (1): cdimage.ubuntu.com
Starting new HTTP connection (1): cdimage.ubuntu.com
Download directory set to /home/david/Downloads/phablet-flash/127
Retrieving files
Not enough space in /data, found 854M
david@Inspiron-8100:~$
```

my tablet is an 8gig and I have a 4 gig SD card mounted. However,my internal storage shows only 850 megs available. The zip file for Ubuntu is a little over 650 megs. yes I know its a compressed file. Is there any way to get past this issue using my SD mounted card or the internal SD?

Comment: How about if I wipe the device and remove the android 4.0

Comment: maybe I can use $ fastboot flashall -w

Comment: I'm guessing you have full disk encryption enabled and the 850 megs is your kernel staging area.

Comment: My guess is..I have missed a step somewhere. I will re-try the process being careful to observe each and every step. Thanks for the response.

Comment: It may be possible to use the command menu, from within Recovery Mode, but I don't have any documentation. *Just the try the standard methods for now.*

Answer (score 0):

BEFORE YOU STARTED:

**I will assume you have a backup of any Android setup / content.**

---

As you are about to overwrite Android image with Ubuntu Touch, then you should first do a factory reset **OR** just re-image the device with Android (using the recovery method given).

**NOTE:** *I have loaded both **phablet** and **desktop** images to various **Nexus 7** devices (both 8GB and 16GB). I have had no issues with either the **phablet-tool** (automated) or command-line (manual) methods.*